# Media query with rails bootstraps-saas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, bootstrap-sass

I m trying to make media queries with bootstraps. I put this in my application.css.scss file but that doesn't work :

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require_tree 
 *= require_self
 */



@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";




$backgroundNav : #ffffff;
$backgroundBody : #E9E9E9;
$red : #FD0E48;

@media screen and (max-width: 770px){ 

    .body {
        background-color: red;
    }

}


 body {
    background: $backgroundBody;
}
```

What should i do in order to make the query to be detected ?

Comment: To whom are you giving those style? Where is the element(s) selector?

Comment: Your style should work. Inspect the element and see if something is overriding those styles.

Comment: nothing special in my inspection, the background keep the background color  #ffffff that i set for my .post in the application.css.scss

Comment: @jmcastel, do you have strings  `*= require_tree .` and `*= require_self` in your `application.css.scss`?

Comment: @IgorIvancha yes see my edit for the full file

Comment: @jmcastel, `*= require_tree .` with space and dot. after you add it, restart server

Comment: @IgorIvancha Did everything but nothing changes..

Comment: open your app with dev-tools and inspect there why doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`Application.css.scss` is a manifest file and you should define which files you need to require.
If you want to compile codes in your application.css.scss you should add `= require_self` in top of your application.css.scss

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the wrong selector.

```
.body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

`.body` selects an elements with the class `body`, like `<div class="body">foobar</div>`

You probably meant to select the `body` element:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Also, put your `@media` styles after the "normal" ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456981/why-do-i-have-to-put-media-queries-at-the-bottom-of-the-stylesheet).

```
body {
    background: $backgroundBody;
}

/* responsive body styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 770px){
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

[Here's the fiddle - resize the window to see the change](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyrx06kq/).

---

And since RoR has SASS support, why not use it?

```
body {
    background: $backgroundBody;

    @media screen and (max-width: 770px){
        background: $backgroundBody;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your CSS in the media query is wrong.

It should be:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

and not .body as it will search for element that has class "body", example:

```
<p class="body> 
     content
</p>
```

Secondly try to write your media queries (@media styles)after your general css towards the end of the files, i think that should fix the issue.

Hope that helps :)